# EF Core Update Foreign Key in Disconnected Scenario

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have a model class in my Blazor Server project as follows

```cs
public class TestModel
{
     public Client Client { get; set; }
     ... other value types follow etc.
}
```

My `Client` class is defined as below:

```cs
public class Client
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SetupModel> SetupModels { get; set; }
}
```

`Client` loads from a view and will never be updated by my application (users change its value using a dropdown). I am defining this as a one to many relation in `OnModelCreating` as each `Client` can have  many `TestModels`.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(x => x.SetupModels).WithOne(x=> x.Client);
```

The `ClientID` shadow property of `TestModel` need to be updated whenever the user changes the `Client` in a dropdown. I am using local storage to handle drafts so it is not possible to use traditional entity tracking, as I often need to parse json back into the relevant classes. My first attempt was to use `Entry.CurrentValues.SetValues`:

```cs
using var context = Factory.CreateDbContext();
var existing = await context.SetupForm.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == model.ID);
context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

`SetValues` doesn't work for reference properties, however, so I am stuck unable to update the foreign key on my `TestModel` in this disconnected scenario. I have spent several hours on this today and think I am overlooking something simple. How should I handle this scenario?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898383/how-to-insert-with-a-foreign-key-shadow-property-in-ef-core/71904057#71904057

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm following but I don't think that's an ideal solution as it would require me to manually keep track of the entities that changed and call SetForeignKey for each of them. While that's possible it would be best for it to happen automatically. I would also note  that I am willing to forgo the use of shadow properties if it makes my scenario easier to handle.